# Eliminar un elemento de un array PHP por su valor

Tags: php

Tengo el array llamado `$oradoresLecturas`:

```
Array ( [0] => 108 [1] => 107 [2] => 292 [3] => 171 [4] => 172 [5] => 125 [6] => 128 [7] => 130 [8] => 161 [9] => 61 [10] => 249 [11] => 142 [12] => 240 [13] => 258 [14] => 202 [15] => 194 [16] => 241 [17] => 239 [18] => 224 [19] => 122 [20] => 203 [21] => 286 [22] => 215 [23] => 269 [24] => 184 [25] => 201 [26] => 200 [27] => 196 [28] => 195 [29] => 217 [30] => 297 )
```

Y tengo estas dos líneas de código.

```
      $oradorActual = $_GET['id'];
      unset($oradoresLecturas[$oradorActual]);
```

Si yo hago un `print_r($oradorActual)` recibo el valor 108 (porque estoy en la direccion `http://localhost/mitrabajo/?id=108`, por ejemplo)

Entonces lo que yo quiero, es eliminar el valor 108 del array `$oradoresLecturas`.

La cosa es que, si yo luego de

```
      unset($oradoresLecturas[$oradorActual]);
```

Y luego hago `print_r($oradoresLecturas)` continúo viendo el valor 108 dentro del array.

Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias

Comment: Es como si en el valor que paso entre corchetes dentro de unset (en este caso es la variable $oradorActual), php espera que yo le dé la posición del elemento. Pero yo no se en que posicion va a estar dicho elemento, lo unico que sé es su valor. Podria hacer antes, una funcion que busque el elemento y devuelva su posicion. Pero me quedó la duda si es posible eliminar directamente por su valor.

Comment: Finalmente lo solucioné de la manera que comenté más arriba. Guardé en la variable ``$eliminar`` la posicion del elemento que busco: ``$eliminar = array_search($oradorID, array_values($oradoresLecturas));`` y se la pasé al ``unset``:  - ``unset($oradoresLecturas[$eliminar]);``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas conocer el índice del valor, para entonces poder borrarlo del array.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo, mediante `array_search()`:

```
$valor=108;
if (($key = array_search($valor, $arr)) !== false) {
    unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

`array_search()` devuelve la clave del elemento que encuentra, que puede usarse para eliminar ese elemento de la matriz original usando `unset()`. Devolverá `FALSE` en caso de fallo, sin embargo, puede devolver un valor de false-y en caso de éxito (su clave puede ser 0, por ejemplo), por lo que se utiliza el operador de comparación estricta `!==`.

La instrucción `if()` verificará si `array_search()` devolvió un valor y solo realizará una acción si lo hizo.

Fuente: [Respuesta de @Bojangeles en Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225113/5587982).

Comment: Justo llegué a esa misma función y me auto respondi al tiempo que vos me respondías. Sabia que A. Cedano iba a llegar a salvarme la vida, pero no sabia exactamente cuando. Stack Cedano deberia llamarse el sitio en español jaja. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera (no era lo que buscaba pero funciona):**

> La función `unset` espera que le pase la posición del elemento a eliminar, cuando yo solo sabia su valor. Por esto, utilizo la funcion `array_search` que buscará dentro de LOS VALORES (esto lo hará porque al segundo parametro se lo paso dentro de la funcion `array_values`) del array `$oradoresLecturas`  el elemento que le pasé como primer parametro (`$oradorId`). Esta linea retorna la posicion del elemento que busco, y lo almaceno en la variable `$eliminar`.

```
$eliminar = array_search($oradorID, array_values($oradoresLecturas));
```

Ya con la posicion, proceso a utilizar la funcion `unset` de la siguiente manera:

```
unset($oradoresLecturas[$eliminar]);
```